# Dagger2 where inject @Named @Provides in dependent module?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I use dagger2 demo by https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2.
I want to use cached and non_cached retrofit call. I create in NetModule.java

```
@Provides @Named("cached")
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache) {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(cache)
            .build();
    return okHttpClient;
}

@Provides @Named("non_cached")
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClientNonCached() {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .build();
    return okHttpClient;
}
```

GitHubModule.java is dependent on NetModule.java. 
my GitHubComponent.java

```
@UserScope
@Component(dependencies = NetComponent.class, modules = GitHubModule.class)
public interface GitHubComponent {
void inject(DemoDaggerActivity activity);
}
```

my NetComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={ApplicationModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
// downstream components need these exposed
Retrofit retrofit();
OkHttpClient okHttpClient();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences();
}
```

In my `DemoDaggerActivity.java` I inject retrofit:

```
@Inject @Named("cached")
OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient;

@Inject
Retrofit mRetrofit;
```

After rebuild project I get error:

[image]

Where can I tell to dagger, that i want to use cached or non_cached retrofit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your Retrofit provider should use `@Named` annotation for OkHttpClient, for example:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public Retrofit provideRetrofit(@Named("cached") OkHttpClient okHttpClient)
{
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("...")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using kotlin, the correct way to inject named is next:

`@field:[Inject Named("api1")]`.

Source: https://medium.com/@WindRider/correct-usage-of-dagger-2-named-annotation-in-kotlin-8ab17ced6928

Answer (score 3):

You have two methods with same name: `provideOkHttpClient()`. Rename one of them, make them distinct.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin, use:

```kt
@Inject
@field:Named("cached")
lateinit var mOkHttpClient: OkHttpClient
```

Focus on the `@Named` annotation, which is specificed using `@field` [annotation use-site target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) from Kotlin. Since, no `@Target` is specified in `@Named` annotation source code in Dagger for older versions, we need to tell the Kotlin compiler where to apply this annotation, hence the `@field` use-site annotation target. A `FIELD` `@Target` is specified for `@Inject` annotation in the source code, hence we do not need to specify a target for it explicitly and the compiler picks the correct target automatically

Also, when you have multiple annotations, they can be combined in an array-like syntax as:

```kt
@field:[Inject Named("cached")]
lateinit var mOkHttpClient: OkHttpClient
```

For a more thorough understanding, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59925322/7891801).