# What is the purpose of using @field:SerializedName annotation instead of @SerializedName?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, annotations, gson

Normally, I use the `@SerializedName` annotation to map the JSON fields. But, in Google Architecture Component sample projects, I see they use `@field:SerializedName` annotation and I can't find anywhere to read the purpose of using that `@field` annotation.

I'm new to Kotlin and can someone explain or share the ref links to read? Thank you.

```kotlin
@Entity(
    indices = [
        Index("id"),
        Index("owner_login")],
    primaryKeys = ["name", "owner_login"]
)
data class Repo(
    val id: Int,
    @field:SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @field:SerializedName("full_name")
    val fullName: String,
    @field:SerializedName("description")
    val description: String?,
    @field:SerializedName("owner")
    @field:Embedded(prefix = "owner_")
    val owner: Owner,
    @field:SerializedName("stargazers_count")
    val stars: Int
) {...
```

Answer (score 37):

**TL;DR:** The `field:` part is known as a ["use-site target"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets), and makes it clear that the annotation is applied to the [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) of the Kotlin property. It is not strictly necessary in this case, though it can make the code more readable.

---

## Explanation

To simplify, let's say you have:

```kotlin
data class Repo(
    @field:SerializedName("name")
    var name: String
)
```

That code is declaring a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) along with its [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) via the [primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors). Kotlin properties are made up of the property itself, a getter, and—if mutable—a setter. What does all this mean for us? It means there's a lot going on here for just one little property. In this context, the annotation on `name` could<sup>1</sup> apply to any one of the following:

- The constructor parameter.
- The Kotlin property itself.
- The getter.
- The setter.
- The setter's parameter.
- The [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) of the property.

By using `field:`, which is known as a ["use-site target"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets), you make it clear the annotation is applied to the *backing field* of the property. No more ambiguity<sup>1</sup>.

However, I should note that **not** using `field:` in this case would still result in the annotation being applied to the backing field. As described in the documentation below, if no use-site target is used, then Kotlin looks at the `@Target` meta-annotation. From there, it applies the annotation to the first valid target from `param` (constructor parameter), `property` (Koltin property), and `field` (backing field), in that order. The [`@SerializedName`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)<sup>2</sup> annotation is not applicable to `param`s. And due to it being a Java annotation, it can't possibly be applicable to `property`s. But the annotation is applicable to `field`s, and so that's where it would end up.

---

<sup>1. *There's not any true ambiguity, because the rules are clearly defined (see the documentation below). But that's regarding the compiler. For a human, at first glance the code may be unclear, and that's really what matters. The use-site target may not be strictly necessary, but it makes the code more readable (at least, in my opinion).*</sup>

<sup>2. *You've tagged this question with [gson](/questions/tagged/gson), and so that's where I assume the annotation is from.*</sup>

---

## Documentation

Here's the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) discussing this:

> ## Annotation Use-site Targets
>
> When you're annotating a property or a primary constructor parameter, there are multiple Java elements which are generated from the corresponding Kotlin element, and therefore multiple possible locations for the annotation in the generated Java bytecode. To specify how exactly the annotation should be generated, use the following syntax:
>
> ```kotlin
> class Example(@field:Ann val foo,    // annotate Java field
>               @get:Ann val bar,      // annotate Java getter
>               @param:Ann val quux)   // annotate Java constructor parameter
> ```
>
> The same syntax can be used to annotate the entire file. To do this, put an annotation with the target `file` at the top level of a file, before the package directive or before all imports if the file is in the default package:
>
> ```kotlin
> @file:JvmName("Foo")
> package org.jetbrains.demo
> ```
>
> If you have multiple annotations with the same target, you can avoid repeating the target by adding brackets after the target and putting all the annotations inside the brackets:
>
> ```kotlin
> class Example {
>      @set:[Inject VisibleForTesting]
>      var collaborator: Collaborator
> }
> ```
>
> The full list of supported use-site targets is:
>
> - `file`;
> - `property` (annotations with this target are not visible to Java);
> - `field`;
> - `get` (property getter);
> - `set` (property setter);
> - `receiver` (receiver parameter of an extension function or property);
> - `param` (constructor parameter);
> - `setparam` (property setter parameter);
> - `delegate` (the field storing the delegate instance for a delegated property).
>
> To annotate the receiver parameter of an extension function, use the following syntax:
>
> ```kotlin
> fun @receiver:Fancy String.myExtension() { ... }
> ```
>
> If you don't specify a use-site target, the target is chosen according to the `@Target` annotation of the annotation being used. If there are multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target from the following list is used:
>
> - `param`;
> - `property`;
> - `field`.

Answer (score 8):

While it isn't *incorrect* to use `@field:SerializedName(...)` in this case, it *is* unnecessary: the same bytecode will be generated with or without the addition of `field:` because either way only the private backing field will get the annotation. I've never seen an actual project in the wild that prefers `@field:SerializedName` to `@SerializedName` and I think the use by the Google samples is unnecessarily confusing for beginners. You should feel free to ignore it.

Comment: It's true for this specific annotation because it's not applicable to parameters. If an annotation is applicable to parameters and '@field:' is not specified, the annotation will end up on the parameter only and not on the backing field. It's a good idea and style to explicitly specify '@field:' target on all annotations that are expected to end up on the fields to avoid unexpected results.

Answer (score 7):

This might help: [from the kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)

> When you're annotating a property or a primary constructor parameter, there are multiple Java elements which are generated from the corresponding Kotlin element, and therefore multiple possible locations for the annotation in the generated Java bytecode. To specify how exactly the annotation should be generated, use the following syntax:

```
class Example(@field:Ann val foo,    // annotate Java field
              @get:Ann val bar,      // annotate Java getter
              @param:Ann val quux)   // annotate Java constructor parameter
```